# Including a mailto url with subject and body that will open in Gmail/Mailbox apps

Tags: html, email, gmail, mailto

I'm kind of baffled that this mailto url successfully opens a new email appropriately filled out on the iOS mail app, but fails to open anything at all when clicked on in the Gmail and Mailbox apps (most up to date versions):

```
<a href="mailto:email@address.com?subject=This is the subject&body=This is the body">link</a>
```

Any ideas around how to get this mailto url to open in Gmail/Mailbox iOS apps as it does in the standard iOS mail app? Thanks.

Comment: This is platform specific and depends on the user's settings. `mailto` opens emails in the user's "default" email client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug with the Gmail app, see below link.
Leave a comment on that thread so the Gmail team notices :)

https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msgid/gmail/0fac71fe-546f-4dba-a85c-93c28ac1bbc6%40googleproductforums.com

Comment: Really, for six years?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 on this url. Is there an updated one?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your spaces with `%20` in your subject and body.

Like this:

```
<a href="mailto:email@address.com?subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body">link</a>
```

Comment: Also try replacing @ with %40